# How does one avoid mysticism?

Tags: halacha-theory, mysticism-kabbalah, how-to

If someone is a strict Rationalist, and does not believe in many forms of Jewish mysticism, how does one go about avoiding it? I ask because kabbalistic mysticism has infiltrated many halakhoth and practices without a clear distinction of what's going on.

An example would be Qiddush. Originally Qiddush began with "וַיְכֻלּוּ" but due to kabbalistic ideas of word numerology, the words "יוֹם הַשִּׁשִּׁי" were added. Because there are halakhoth that say you can't say a partial verse, certain Rabbis/Communities also added "וַיְהִי עֶרֶב וַיְהִי בֹקֶר " to make it so that you are saying a complete verse. So when you open up a siddur, there are many variations of Qiddush, but none of them retain the original begining with וַיְכֻלּוּ, they also make no mention of why the additions are there, or their history.

So when mysticism that one may severely disagree with has embedded itself so deeply in the tradition that one can't just open a siddur or a book and distinguish it, how does one go about building a life free of mysticism?

Comment: וַיְהִי עֶרֶב וַיְהִי בֹקֶר יוֹם הַשִּׁשִּׁי is not a complete verse, and the reason that phrase was added has nothing to do with numerology AFAIK. Do you have any reason to suspect saying any verses from Genesis is original? I'd suspect it wasn't.

Comment: Are you ok with "Go learn everything and see where the mysticism came in" as an answer? If not, you should [edit] to specify more precisely what you are looking for.

Comment: @DoubleAA i would be happy with that answer if i were to be given a methodology with which i could learn these things. If i ask a Rabbi and he doesn't know, if i pick up a current halakhic book that doesn't mention it, then saying "go learn" isn't that helpful. If i asked how can i avoid getting the flu, an answer stating "Go and learn everything" isn't helpful. An answer saying "Go to a class on public health, take classes on biology and immunization" would be a much more helpful answer.

Comment: You're never going to find one book that covers every possible issue... Go take classes on Judaism and Halacha. What you are proposing is a big undertaking.

Comment: @DoubleAA i'm casting doubt that even most classes on halacha would even be aware of this issue, i brought up the kiddush issue with a few Rabbeim and they were completely unaware of this information. i accidentally stumbled upon it in the book "Why Jews Do What They Do" which contains excerpts from the book Minhagei Yisrael, which traces historical developments of certain halakhoth.

Comment: Your doubt is definitely misplaced. Perhaps you are simply asking rabbis who haven't spent time learning that particular sugya much (not surprising as it has very little halakhic relevance). Remember not everyone with the title 'rabbi' is an expert on all of halacha. Find a class that studies matters in depth from the original sources to modern practice.

Comment: Aaron, the passuk actually begins וירא אלקים את כל אשר עשה

Comment: Mysticism in Judaism goes back at least a thousand years. That's what is on written record. The Talmud was finished 1500 years ago. What year is your cutoff for accepting mainstream views of Jewish leaders as binding? Somewhere between those two dates? What about the Rishonim who lived during and after the mystics? Are they acceptable?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt i know the verse goes back even further, but many start it there because apparently there's an atnach under wa-yehi and many consider starting on an atnach and ending at the sof pasuk to be a complete verse. Not that i agree with this, but the ways in which people stretch halacha to mix with Kabbalah is a bit much

Comment: @Aaron, FWIW, my family recites the whole passuk and we don't often hold like kabbalah.

Answer (score 5):

Study a *halacha* book. Check its sources, and look them up. Check their sources and look them up. Check their sources and look them up. Etc. You'll have an original source for every (or almost every) aspect of *halacha*. Study those original sources and all their descendants, and you'll be able to see which aspects of *halacha* come from *kabala*. (I've no source for saying this is a good method, but it seems like one to me.)

---

Caveat lector: I recommend this only as an exercise in *talmud Tora* and not as an exercise in (as you say) "building a life free of mysticism". As we see from the huge (albeit partial) [list of *halacha* authorities who have incorporated mysticism in their *halacha* works](/a/3833), one shouldn't build a life free of mysticism. (At least, not as far as I can tell. Consult your rabbi for a practical ruling.)